# How to check if there is greater than one item in a list python

Tags: python, rubiks-cube

I am making a code that generates a Rubik's cube scramble and I used `if scramble:` to see if there was anything in the list in the for loop. I am unsure of how to check if there is anything in list index > 0. The code is here (please don't judge my coding, it's not final I still have some cleaning up to do of the code and I am only doing GCSE computer science at the moment)

```
scrambling = True
while scrambling:
    scramble = []
    for i in range(0,30):
        while True:
            chosen = r.choice(moves)
            if scramble:
                if scramble[i-1] != chosen:
                    if chosen[0] != scramble[i-1][0]:
                        break
                    else:
                        pass
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                break
        scramble.append(chosen)
    if opposites[scramble[15]] != opposites.get(scramble[16]):
        if opposites[scramble[14]] != opposites.get(scramble[15]):
            scrambling = False
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the length of the list:

```py
if len(scramble) > 1:
    #...
```